# Is it possible to write a function with "self" as an argument without defining a class?

Tags: python, function, oop, object, self

I am trying to cut some lines of code by implementing functions. I was looking into functions that take themselves as an argument, as in oop. For example:

```
def drop_columns(self, columns):
    return self.drop(columns, axis = 1)

df.drop_columns(['id', 'date'])
```

or

```
def print_shape(self):
    print(self.shape)

df.print_shape()
```

But more sophisticated of course. However, the code does not work. If I feed it a data frame, it throws an error:
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'print_shape'`

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You can name the parameters of your functions whatever you want; the behavior of functions retrieved from a class instance ("methods") has *absolutely nothing* to do with the specific name `self`.

Comment: You could of course just do `print_shape(df)` as a utility function.

Comment: or you could subclass DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a method on an instance of a class, that instance passes itself as the first parameter. We usually call that parameter `self`, for convenience.

This only works if the method is bound to the instance in the first place. When you do `df.print_shape()`, it doesn't work, because you never attached `print_shape()` to `df` in any way.

Both of the following will work, though:

```
# approach 1: call it as a function
print_shape(df)

# approach 2: assign the function as an attribute of df, then call it as a method
setattr(df, 'print_shape', print_shape)
df.print_shape()
```

Approach 1 is preferred, as it's generally better practice not to modify objects that you didn't create yourself (and not to do so dynamically like this). But knowing that Approach 2 exists gives some perspective/insight into how python works as a language. If you were sitting inside `print_shape()`, unable to look at anything going on outside of it, you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: Is it possible to map object methods like drop, e.g. `map(drop(['column'], axis = 1), df)`? I am looking for  a concise solution to drop columns from multiple data frames.

Comment: Not *directly*, but you could maybe do a workaround using a lambda function, e.g. `map(lambda d:drop(d, ['column'], axis=1), df)` or something. The problem with `map()` is that it only ever passes one argument, so if you want to call something with multiple arguments you have to do so as a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing classes and OOP with functions. In your case, don't treat your inputs as objects, rather arguments to your functions:

```
drop_columns(df, ['id', 'date'])
print_shape(df)
```

These calls should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach here would be to subclass from `DataFrame` and build your convenience functions in this class:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class EnhancedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def print_shape(self):
        print(self.shape)
    def print_foo(self):
        print('This is the \'foo\'')

data = np.array(np.random.randint(0,100,(3,4)))
columns = ['A','B','A','C']
index = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3']
frame = EnhancedDataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

And then you should be able to do like:

[image]

So getting to the root of your problem:

> However, the code does not work. If I feed it a data frame, it throws an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'print_shape'`

We've now implemented our own class (`EnhancedDataFrame`) which **is** a `DataFrame` (well, ok, technically it inherits from `DataFrame`). It implements all of the methods you'd normally expect in a `DataFrame`, but also now includes whatever convenience methods you might want to add!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking the second example... What you can do is:

```
    def __init__(self, shape=None):
        self.shape = shape
```

Now, call `print_shape(Shape())`, or `print_shape(Shape('circle'))`.

Since, print shape is not bound to any class (or object), it can treat self as a parameter.